# Google Maps Flutter disable center Marker after onTap()

Tags: flutter, google-maps, camera, center, marker

I use flutter_google_maps and after tapping on a Marker the Marker is centered automatically on the map.
Is there a way to disable this?

Thanks
Joerg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the time of creating the marker make sure you are passing `consumeTapEvents` to `true`, and it will do the magic.
Follow the below line of code:

```
Marker marker = Marker(markerId: markerId, consumeTapEvents: true)
```